# Random mouse click events all over my laptop. What can I do?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, mouse-click

Details:

I got a Dell vostro 1015 laptop. Recently I reinstalled windows 7 ultimate (32-bit) on the C:
(By reinstall I mean create a new windows copy, which keeps your old files in C:/windows.old)

I started getting random right/left click events the same day. Let me tell you what it's not, as i found out by elimination:

- First off, my touchpad conked off about a year ago. I use a dell
  external usb mouse. So it's not that.
- It's not the mouse either. Happens even when the mouse is disconnected.
- My drivers are updated.
- My keyboard keys are not stuck. Moreover, I'm getting both right-click event, which causes the context menu to pop up, and left click event, which can happen rapidly multiple times and turn into a double-click event. That rules out the menu key from keyboard.

Frequency-wise, the events can stop altogether for upto 2 hours. Or can happen about 30 times in 10 seconds. On an average, it's about 4-5 events per 15 minutes.

All I installed after windows was the latest versions of chrome, firefox and vlc media player.

Annoyed, I did a second reinstall of windows (created new copy in C:). The issue still persists.

It could be a driver issue or a virus. I don't know what.

Interestingly, the majority of the click events are left, but when I check *switch primary and secondary buttons* in *mouse properties* (to reverse the mouse button functions), the majority of events are right-click.

Please help.

Comment: Did you completely disable the touchpad in the Device Manager?

Comment: @Brian: Thanks for the interest. After reinstall, i don't even have a touchpad driver. i'll see if it shows in the device manager and disable it.

Comment: @Brian: it can't be the touchpad anyway because in that case i'd get only one click event: left-click

Comment: The touchpad doesn't have the feature where you can define a tap in a certain region as a right-click?

Comment: @Brian: No it doesn't. Also, I checked, device manager doesn't even show the touchpad.

Comment: Very strange.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you try moving everything from the Windows.old folder to an external drive and then disconnect that? If it's a simple virus or troll program, that might already fix it. If yes, you can slowly move the files back to see when it starts again.